# Django Guardian TemplateSyntaxError In Admin

Tags: django

Trying to edit object permissions using django-guardian in the admin site I get this error.

Caught VariableDoesNotExist while rendering: Failed lookup for key [adminform] in u'[{}, {\'csrf_token\': }, {\'debug\': True, \'sql_queries\': [{\'stacktrace\':...

Template error

In template /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/grappelli/templates/admin/change_form.html, error at line 34

The line where the error occurs.

```
var related_lookup_fields_fk = {% get_related_lookup_fields_fk adminform.model_admin %};
```

I'm using grappelli and south if that makes any difference.

My model

```
class Alert(models.Model):
    """Alert for product updates"""
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    message = models.CharField(help_text="What has changed?",blank=True, max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True, editable=False)    

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.message

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']
        permissions = (
            ('view_alert', 'View Alert'),
        )
```

Admin.py

```
class AlertAdmin(GuardedModelAdmin):
    pass
admin.site.register(Alert, AlertAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grappelli is the key here.

This is related issue #51 (https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian/issues/51) which was fixed with https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian/commit/a21b044711266534eaef5e58397d0701ec101058.

Unfortunately, I haven't released new *django-guardian* yet so you can try using pip to install package directly from github:

```
pip install -e git+git://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian.git@a21b044711266534eaef5e58397d0701ec101058#egg=django-guardian-1.0.4.dev
```

Hope that helps.